# Consistent GPS updates - AlarmManager or requestLocationUpdates()?

Tags: android, gps

I need to get GPS location updates every minute (battery life isn't a problem as the device(s) will be charged within the vehicles). It's a company delivery app, with vehicle tracking, used in conjunction with Google maps, to track journeys for delivery planners etc.

I've used both AlarmManager and LocationManager.requestLocationUpdates() with a listener. The later seems a bit ropey and going by the documentation, it may or may not give a location. But I've seen that even though the minTime is set to 1 minute and distance is 0/1, I'm still only seeing updates once or twice per 5 min period.

```
    private void startGeoLocationSender()
{       
    LocationManager locationManager = (LocationManager)getSystemService(Context.LOCATION_SERVICE);
    LocationListener locationListener = new GeoLocationListener(this);
    // MINIMUM TIME TO REQUEST , MIN DISTANCE TO REQUEST, LISTENER
    locationManager.requestLocationUpdates(LocationManager.GPS_PROVIDER, 
            AppSettings.COLLECTOR_PROC_1_MINS, 
            AppSettings.COLLECTOR_DISTANCE_1_M, locationListener);      
}
```

So, is it worth me just going back to an AlarmManager and forcing an update manually for it to be reliable? Or is there another method, which is 100% reliable given a specific update time? What is better suited to my requirement?

PS. I'm very aware of the other '000s of topics on the subject, but I've never seen such a Good Vs Evil trend. Some folk swear by location listeners, and others only AlarmManagers.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I am not sure of a better way, so I would recommend AlarmManager.

Answer (score 1):

If you use only LocationListener you can't ensure that will receive update in interval time needed.
I really think that the best option is the AlarmManager or a Scheluder Service with a trigger to your LocationListener.